# Angular 5 (& more): HTMLElement with @ViewChild

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive, formio

I have to reference an `htmlElement` with a `@ViewChild()`, is there any way to this? I have to create an HTMLElement and then try to assign a reference to a `viewChild` or something similar.
THank you for your attention.

Comment: Can you describe more what are you trying to achieve, are you trying to create that HTMLElement dynamically or is it already present in the dom ?

Comment: Show your code @j Doe, so that we can help you!! :)

Comment: I'm trying to define a formio custom component, and i have to define the template to show on my custom component with "document.createElement(...)" because the registration of my custom component with formio don't le me show the template i have defined in "templateUrl", and i need to inject some variable to my template

Answer (score 11):

I came here looking for a way to get the `HTMLElement` from a `ViewChild` that's selecting a child component. I realize that this is not exactly what the question is about. Still, it might be helpful.

This can be achived using the `read` option inside the `ViewChild.opts`:

```html
<my-child-component #mySelector></my-child-component>
```

```
@ViewChild('mySelector', {read: ElementRef})
childElement: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

doSomething() {
  const htmlElement = childElement.nativeElement;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not so simple. ViewChild should be used for:

- any class with the Component or Directive decorator
- a template reference variable as a string (e.g. query  with ViewChild('cmp'))
- any provider defined in the child component tree of the current
  component (e.g. ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)
- any provider defined through a string token (e.g.
  ViewChild('someToken') someTokenVal: any)
- a TemplateRef (e.g. query  with
  ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;)

In your case better to use last option:

```html
<input #testInput >
```

TS:

```
...
@ViewChild('testInput') input;
...
```

Comment: Not really, you can reference normal HTML elements as well.

Comment: [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) - describes no way to provide plain HTMLElement as @ViewChild

Comment: @NorthHalcyon - `ViewChild` can refer to an HTML element with a template reference variable.

Comment: - any class with the Component or Directive decorator
- a template reference variable as a string (e.g. query <my-component #cmp></my-component> with ViewChild('cmp'))
- any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)
- any provider defined through a string token (e.g. ViewChild('someToken') someTokenVal: any)
- a TemplateRef (e.g. query <ng-template></ng-template> with ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;) - what of them?

Comment: The one with the template reference variable. You can see an example in the "DOM Elements" section of [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/).

Comment: agree, but it is not an _any_ HTMLElement mentioned by author of original question

Comment: You could edit your answer to better explain what you mean exactly.